# What to do in a herd of angry cows?

Tags: hiking, animals

Sometimes I have to go through a herd of cows on a pasture when hiking in mountains. Cows are generally very peaceful creatures and there is no problem usually.

However, I missed this `"Danger! Bulls in herd!"` sign today. I walked quite swiftly, cows were going out of my way and then I met a bull. It was standing right in front of me, very angry, pawing the ground with hoof. "Alright, let's go back" I decided, but it was too late. Cows were all around, obviously nervous, because the bull was nervous. They were mooing, snorting, kicking each other, getting panicked and moving closer to me. It was pretty scary.

What should one do in such a situation? Run? Shout and wave his hands? Sit down and try to look small and friendly?

Comment: Considering you survived to tell the tale, I'd suppose that whatever you ended up doing was rather effective.